# OpenBSD Memory protection mechanisms that are not enabled by default?

Tags: security, memory, openbsd

Besides the **"S" option for [malloc.conf](http://man.openbsd.org/malloc.conf)** and increasing **kern.stackgap_random** and removing the **wxallowed** mount option, what else **memory-related** hardening mechanism are in OpenBSD that can be turned on and it is not enabled by default?

Even options would be useful if we have to re-compile the kernel, if minimal source code modification is needed.

Usually they don't enable it because many application, exampe from ports would crash because of bad code.

Tried to get lists/ideas from grsecurity (if there is any, that is not already used in OpenBSD), but it is hard when you are not a programmer: https://grsecurity.net/features.php

Comment: `securelevel=2` https://man.openbsd.org/securelevel prevents non-console root from doing some nasty things. `pledge` https://man.openbsd.org/pledge is "on" by default but some programs need to incorporate it in their source code

Comment: Thank you! Although securelevel is related to make a system more secure, it has nothing to do with memory security. Also, pledge is there by default on OpenBSD, the question was for non-default functions.

Answer (score 1):

> "...  what else memory-related hardening mechanism are in OpenBSD that can be turned on and it is not enabled by default?
>
> Even options would be useful if we have to re-compile the kernel [or programs I use], if minimal source code modification is needed.".

What I dug up so far:

Always update to the latest stable version of the Kernel. Also look at http://www.trustedbsd.org/. Read references such as [Wikipedia's OpenBSD security features webpage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenBSD_security_features).

OpenBSD **memory related** security features:

- [Address Space Layout Randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) (ASLR): setting the sysctl **vm.randomize_mmap** to **1** (should be on by default, but it's off in DragonflyBSD and apparently not implemented in FreeBSD).
- Use [timingsafe_bcmp](https://man.openbsd.org/timingsafe_bcmp.3)(3) and timingsafe_memcmp(3) instead of bcmp(3) or memcmp(3).
- Use the [explicit_bzero(3)](https://man.openbsd.org/explicit_bzero) variant instead of bzero(3) to clear sensitive memory (like password variables).
- Position Independent Executables (PIE): [Link with **-pie**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) or **--pic-executable**

  Create a position independent executable. This is currently **only supported on ELF** platforms. Position independent executables are similar to shared libraries in that they are relocated by the dynamic linker to the virtual address the OS chooses for them (which can vary between invocations). Like normal dynamically linked executables they can be executed and symbols defined in the executable cannot be overridden by shared libraries.
- Randomized [mmap(2)](https://man.openbsd.org/mmap.2): Don't use MAP_FIXED. Check with mquery.
- Replace random(): [rand(3)](https://man.openbsd.org/rand.3), [random(3)](https://man.openbsd.org/random.3), and [rand48(3)](https://man.openbsd.org/rand48.3), etc. replaced with BSD's [arc4random(3)](https://man.openbsd.org/arc4random).
- Consider using [reallocarray(3)](https://man.openbsd.org/reallocarray) and recallocarray(3) and freezero(3) for sensitive data instead of malloc(3), calloc(3), or realloc(3).
- [Stack Smashing Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenBSD_security_features#Memory_protection) (SSP): GCC + Propolice (SSP) activated by  default to build all libraries and applications.
- [KERN_STACKGAPRANDOM](https://man.openbsd.org/sysctl.2) (**kern.stackgap_random**) Sets the range of the random value added to the stack pointer on each program execution. The random value is added to make buffer overflow exploitation slightly harder. The **bigger the number, the harder it is** to brute force this added protection, but it also means bigger waste of memory. Default: **262144**.
- Use the new [strlcpy(3)](https://man.openbsd.org/strlcpy) and strlcat(3) instead of strcpy(3), strcat(3), strncpy(3) or strncat(3) - allows safe string copies.
- Use [strtonum(3)](https://man.openbsd.org/strtonum.3) function instead of the atoi(3) and strtol(3) family of interfaces.
- [W^X policy](https://man.openbsd.org/mount.8):  A page  may be  both  writable  or  executable, but not  both. Hence W^X. The idea is to create a [.rodata](https://man.openbsd.org/mprotect.2) segment with the PROT_READ attribute only thus it loses the PROT_EXEC attribute.

Comment: but the q was for memory protection besides the mentioned ones by me " that can be turned on and it is not enabled by default" - but please, please keep this great list, Thanks!